# Collections Search in List

Tags: java, collections

i have two list

```
Collection<String> listOne = new ArrayList<String>();
Collection<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<String>();

for(PermissionDataObject permissionDataObject : selectedPermissions)
  listOne.add(permissionDataObject.getPermissionName());        

for(String selectedPermissions : selectedList)
  listTwo.add(selectedPermissions);

Collection<String> similarPermissions = new HashSet<String>(listOne);
Collection<String> differentPermissions = new HashSet<String>();

differentPermissions.addAll(listOne);
differentPermissions.addAll(listTwo);

similarPermissions.retainAll(listTwo);
differentPermissions.removeAll(similarPermissions);

System.out.printf("One:%s%nTwo:%s%nSimilar:%s%nDifferent:%s%n", listOne, listTwo, similarPermissions, differentPermissions);
```

output is

```
One:[MENU_CREATION, ROLE_CREATION]
Two:[CREATE_BRANCH, CREATE_COUNTRY, MENU_CREATION, ROLE_CREATION]
Similar:[ROLE_CREATION, MENU_CREATION]
Different:[CREATE_BRANCH, CREATE_COUNTRY]
```

the above code is perfectly working i got different collection

but i want to check the listTwo and differentPermissions, if different and listTwo is equals doSomething if different and listTwo is not equals doSomthing

i have below code, when different has one value its working, if different has more values the loop is break up

```
for (Iterator<String> it = differentPermissions.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
    String diffString = it.next();
    String selectedString = selectedList.listIterator().next();

    log.info("---diffString---" + diffString);
    log.info("---selectedString---" + selectedString);

    if(diffString == selectedString){
         System.out.println("----permission added----" + diffString);
    }else{
         System.out.println("----permission deleted----" + diffString);
         }
    }
```

any ideas, is great to me...

Thanks Pradeep

**[EDIT]**
Small change in my code see below full code

```
Collection<String> listOne = Arrays.asList("MENU_CREATION", "ROLE_CREATION");
        Collection<String> listTwo = Arrays.asList("CREATE_BRANCH", "CREATE_COUNTRY", "MENU_CREATION", "ROLE_CREATION");

        Collection<String> similar = new HashSet<String>(listOne);
        Collection<String> different = new HashSet<String>();

        different.addAll(listOne);
        different.addAll(listTwo);

        similar.retainAll(listTwo);
        different.removeAll(similar);

         System.out.printf("One:%s%nTwo:%s%nSimilar:%s%nDifferent:%s%n", listOne, listTwo, similar, different);

        for (Iterator<String> it = different.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {

            String diffString = it.next();
            String selectedString = listTwo.iterator().next();

            if (diffString.equals(selectedString)) {
                System.out.println("----permission added----" + diffString);
            } else {
                System.out.println("----permission deleted----" + diffString);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look at your code, try to use `diffString.equals(selectedString)` instead of `diffString == selectedString`.

Then, for your problem, I don't really understand what you want to compare. Do you want the lists to match perfectly, or you want to check if the items of your list that have the same index match?

Answer (score 0):

`==` compares the references of the objects and not their content. Use `diffString.equals(selectedString)` in order to compare `String`s.

Comment: i am also checking .equals insted of ==

Answer (score 0):

To find out same/different items in a collections I would recommend using Set interface with standard set operations like union, intersection etc.
You can use google Guava library to help you with that: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained

```
Set<String> wordsWithPrimeLength = ImmutableSet.of("one", "two", "three", "six", "seven", "eight");
Set<String> primes = ImmutableSet.of("two", "three", "five", "seven");

SetView<String> intersection = Sets.intersection(primes, wordsWithPrimeLength); // contains "two", "three", "seven"
// I can use intersection as a Set directly, but copying it can be more efficient if I use it a lot.
return intersection.immutableCopy();
```

You won't have to iterate over your collections items to find out what you need. Hope that helps in the future implementations